# Exercise 4, Chapter 6 in Wald's book

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, black-holes, gravitational-redshift

I would like to understand the solution of point b) in the mentioned exercise, which reads

> Let $(M,g_{ab})$ be a stationary spacetime with timelike Killing field $\xi^a.$ Let $V^2=-\xi^a\xi_a$.
>
> a) Show that the acceleration $a^b=u^a\nabla_au^b$ of a stationary observer is given by $a^b=\nabla^b\ln V$.
>
> b) Suppose in addition that $(M,g_{ab})$ is asymptotically flat, i.e, that there exist coodinates $t,x,y,z$ [with $\xi^a=(\partial/\partial t)^a$] such that the components of $g_{ab}$ approach $\text{diag}(-1,1,1,1)$ as $r\to\infty$, where $r=(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{1/2}.$ As in the case of the Schwarzschild metric, the ''energy as measured at infinity'' of a particle of mass $m$ and 4-velocity $u^a$ is $E=-m\xi^au_a$. Suppose a particle of mass $m$ is held stationary by a massless string, with the other end of the string held by a stationary observer at large $r$. Let $F$ denote the force exerted by the string on the particle. According to part a) we have $F=mV^{-1}(\nabla_aV\nabla^aV)^{1/2}$. Use conservation of energy arguments to show that the force exerted by the observer at infinity on the other end of the string is $F_\infty=VF.$ Thus the magnitude of the force exerted at infinity differs from the force exerted locally by the redshift factor.

How should I use the conservation of the energy to solve the problem? Why does energy take that form?
Equivalently, from a mathematical point of view, where does the redshift factor $V$ come out from in $F_\infty$?

Answer (score 0):

Conservation of energy means that the quantity
$$ E = -g_{\mu\nu}\xi^\mu \dot x^\nu$$
along any geodesic with tangent vector $\dot x^\mu$.

Comment: Ok, perfect I proved that this quantity is conserved (even though I don't really get why it is called energy as measured at infinity).
The question is how I should use the conservation of this quantity (not whether it is conserved) to prove that there is a redshift factor in the force F.

Comment: It's energy because for a timelike worldlike $x(t)$ it's the gamma factor, i.e. $E/m$. Maybe try considering the work done in a small displacement in the $r$ direction, and calculate the proper length using the metric, and insist that the proper length of the rope is fixed, and then see that the $delta r$ at both ends need to be related by $V$.